# Pgfplots: wrong legend image

Tags: pgfplots, legend

Convince yourself about the color and image of the marker and line (where there should only be one at the time). Effectively the color and marker/line stay at the default value even though specified differently.

What am I doing wrong or is it a bug?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[legend style={at={(0.2,0.5)},anchor=north}]
\addplot table[col sep=comma, color=red, only marks] {
0,2
2,4
5,5
};
\addlegendentry{A};
\addplot table[col sep=comma, color=red, mark=none] {
0,2.4
5,5.4
};
\addlegendentry{Fit A};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Both traces are supposed to be red and one without marker and the other without line but the legend shows both.

[image: Both traces should be red.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is no bug, you are just putting the directives at the wrong place.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[legend style={at={(0.2,0.5)},anchor=north}]
\addplot[color=red, only marks] table[col sep=comma] {
0,2
2,4
5,5
};
\addlegendentry{A};
\addplot[color=red, mark=none] table[col sep=comma] {
0,2.4
5,5.4
};
\addlegendentry{Fit A};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]